# Не могу установить MySQL на убутнту

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Устанавливал через sudo apt-get install mysql-server

Лог
'''

```
we@DESKTOP-Q7LMU3C:~$ sudo apt-get install mysql-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl
libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2
libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server-8.0
mysql-server-core-8.0
Suggested packages:
libdata-dump-perl libipc-sharedcache-perl libwww-perl mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libcgi-fast-perl libcgi-pm-perl libencode-locale-perl libevent-core-2.1-7 libevent-pthreads-2.1-7 libfcgi-perl libhtml-parser-perl
libhtml-tagset-perl libhtml-template-perl libhttp-date-perl libhttp-message-perl libio-html-perl liblwp-mediatypes-perl libmecab2
libtimedate-perl liburi-perl mecab-ipadic mecab-ipadic-utf8 mecab-utils mysql-client-8.0 mysql-client-core-8.0 mysql-common mysql-server
mysql-server-8.0 mysql-server-core-8.0
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/36.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 319 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-common.
(Reading database ... 81885 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../0-mysql-common_5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../1-mysql-client-core-8.0_8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-client-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../2-mysql-client-8.0_8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../3-libevent-core-2.1-7_2.1.11-stable-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../4-libevent-pthreads-2.1-7_2.1.11-stable-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libmecab2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../5-libmecab2_0.996-10build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-core-8.0.
Preparing to unpack .../6-mysql-server-core-8.0_8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mysql-common (5.8+1.0.5ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server-8.0.
(Reading database ... 82103 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-mysql-server-8.0_8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_amd64.deb ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld [ OK ]
Unpacking mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-tagset-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-4_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liburi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../02-liburi-perl_1.76-2_all.deb ...
Unpacking liburi-perl (1.76-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-parser-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libhtml-parser-perl_3.72-5_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-5) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-pm-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libcgi-pm-perl_4.46-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libfcgi-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libfcgi-perl_0.79-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libfcgi-perl (0.79-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcgi-fast-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libcgi-fast-perl_1%3a2.15-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libencode-locale-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libencode-locale-perl_1.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhtml-template-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libhtml-template-perl_2.97-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtimedate-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../09-libtimedate-perl_2.3200-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libtimedate-perl (2.3200-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-date-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../10-libhttp-date-perl_6.05-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libio-html-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../11-libio-html-perl_1.001-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package liblwp-mediatypes-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../12-liblwp-mediatypes-perl_6.04-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhttp-message-perl.
Preparing to unpack .../13-libhttp-message-perl_6.22-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking libhttp-message-perl (6.22-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-utils.
Preparing to unpack .../14-mecab-utils_0.996-10build1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-utils (0.996-10build1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic.
Preparing to unpack .../15-mecab-ipadic_2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mecab-ipadic-utf8.
Preparing to unpack .../16-mecab-ipadic-utf8_2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package mysql-server.
Preparing to unpack .../17-mysql-server_8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libmecab2:amd64 (0.996-10build1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-core-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libhtml-tagset-perl (3.20-4) ...
Setting up liblwp-mediatypes-perl (6.04-1) ...
Setting up libencode-locale-perl (1.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-utils (0.996-10build1) ...
Setting up libevent-core-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Setting up libio-html-perl (1.001-1) ...
Setting up libtimedate-perl (2.3200-1) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up libfcgi-perl (0.79-1) ...
Setting up liburi-perl (1.76-2) ...
Setting up libevent-pthreads-2.1-7:amd64 (2.1.11-stable-1) ...
Setting up libhttp-date-perl (6.05-1) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab. This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up mysql-server-core-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
Setting up mecab-ipadic-utf8 (2.7.0-20070801+main-2.1) ...
Compiling IPA dictionary for Mecab. This takes long time...
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/unk.def ... 40
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
/usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/model.def is not found. skipped.
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adj.csv ... 27210
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adnominal.csv ... 135
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Adverb.csv ... 3032
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Auxil.csv ... 199
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Conjunction.csv ... 171
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Filler.csv ... 19
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Interjection.csv ... 252
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adjv.csv ... 3328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.adverbal.csv ... 795
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.csv ... 60477
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.demonst.csv ... 120
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.nai.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.name.csv ... 34202
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.number.csv ... 42
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.org.csv ... 16668
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.others.csv ... 151
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.place.csv ... 72999
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.proper.csv ... 27328
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Noun.verbal.csv ... 12146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Others.csv ... 2
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp-col.csv ... 91
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Postp.csv ... 146
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Prefix.csv ... 221
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Suffix.csv ... 1393
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Symbol.csv ... 208
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/Verb.csv ... 130750
emitting double-array: 100% |###########################################|
reading /usr/share/mecab/dic/ipadic/matrix.def ... 1316x1316
emitting matrix : 100% |###########################################|

done!
update-alternatives: using /var/lib/mecab/dic/ipadic-utf8 to provide /var/lib/mecab/dic/debian (mecab-dictionary) in auto mode
Setting up libhtml-parser-perl (3.72-5) ...
Setting up libhttp-message-perl (6.22-1) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.31-0ubuntu0.20.04.1) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
* Stopping MySQL database server mysqld [ OK ]
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Setting up libcgi-pm-perl (4.46-1) ...
Setting up libhtml-template-perl (2.97-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libcgi-fast-perl (1:2.15-1) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Processing triggers for systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.19) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.9) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
mysql-server-8.0
mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

'''

А вот что если хочу запустить
we@DESKTOP-Q7LMU3C:~$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (13)

Comment: Ну вроде ж явно ихним по белому: "mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet". Конфигурируй...

Comment: Это наверное хороший совет, не учитывая, что должно из под коробки работать, что я там настроить могу, если я с базой ещё ни разу не работал

Comment: *должно из под коробки работать* Так оно ж не в курсе, как именно ему работать... *я с базой ещё ни разу не работал* Так, может, лучше начать с чего попроще - скажем, с [online fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mRIKm8tU)?

Comment: Я не понимаю, почему я смотрю гайд на установку - там работает, а у меня нет. Альтернативной установки через "конфигурацию" я не нашёл

Comment: @Akina должно работать, здоровая убунта создаёт mysql.cnf автоматически

Comment: Если у вас в mysql ещё нет никаких ценных данных/конфигов, попробуйте удалить всё и потом установить заново `sudo apt autoremove --purge mysql-server-8.0 mysql-common` / `sudo mv /etc/mysql /etc/mysql.old` / `sudo apt install mysql-server`

Comment: Уже как я только не пробовал удалять, в том числе и ваше способ не помог